# How to read a QR from an image in the device

Tags: ios, swift3, qr-code

I have used already many times the reading of a `QR code` from the camera in my iOS apps.
But this time I want to get my `QR code` from an image which is already stored on my device, say for example in the photo album.
**What is the best way to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreImage to achieve this. You can use the CIDetector class to check if CIDetectorType is of type `CIDetectorTypeQRCode`. You can make use of this [code](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/iOS8-day-by-day/blob/master/13-coreimage-detectors/LiveDetection/LiveDetection/ViewController.swift)

Function that they use to detect QRCode from the image is

```
 func performQRCodeDetection(_ image: CIImage) -> (outImage: CIImage?, decode: String) {
    var resultImage: CIImage?
    var decode = ""
    if let detector = detector {
      let features = detector.features(in: image)
      for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
        resultImage = drawHighlightOverlayForPoints(image, topLeft: feature.topLeft, topRight: feature.topRight,
          bottomLeft: feature.bottomLeft, bottomRight: feature.bottomRight)
        decode = feature.messageString!
      }
    }
    return (resultImage, decode)
}
```

Comment: OK. Just a basic question where do you get the CIImage from. I have basically no experience with using the photo album.

Comment: Inside the  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate function you will get the image like

      let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

You can convert it to CIImage like
        let cIImage = CIImage(image: image!)

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hope this will help you